# Hide some button by method onClick in android

Tags: android, button, onclick, hide

I have some button, and I want when I click on a button, it will do some bussiness logic and hide this button, I have 14 button so I override 14 method onClick for those 14 button. Is there another good way to do that? I want overrider onclick method 1 time.
Please help me. Thanks a lot.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint01"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHint08"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint08"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnHint01"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint02"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHint08"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint01"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint04"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnHint03"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnHint03"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint03"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint03"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHint08"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint02"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint05"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHint08"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint04"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint06"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHint08"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint05"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint07"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnHint06"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnHint06"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint06"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint09"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHint01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint01"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHint02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint02"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHint05"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint03"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHint04"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint04"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint13"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHint05"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint05"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHint14"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHint06"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHint06"
    android:text="@string/none"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use swict case in `onClick` like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            //your business logic
            break;

        case R.id.btn2:
            //Your businesslogic
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: I have presumed that your activity is implementing `android.view.View.OnClickListener`. And you have added this:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

after initialization in `onCreate`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Here class should implement `OnClickListener`

Comment: I know that @Aniruddha :) I had presumed that the OP would know that.

Answer (score 0):

there are two way for this.
1- Switch case
2-if else

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity(or Fragment) implements View.OnClickListener{
        Button btn1,btn2,btn3;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_id1:
                //your some logic
                break;

            case R.id.btn_id2:
                //Your some logic
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    //And after you init buttons set for each clickListener 
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            btn1=..;
            btn2=..;
            btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement onClickListener in your activity like

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

}
```

and override

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            //do what u need to do here
            break;

        case R.id.rb_key_mismatch:
           //do what u need to do here
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnClickListener

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

```
  case R.id.b1:
     //do something
     break;
  case R.id.b2:
    //do something
    break;
 }
```

}

Switch-case is easier to maintain than if-else, and this implementation doesn't require making many class variables.